# Calculate Last task and Last Event age on Opportunity page

Tags: trigger, formula, activities

I have an issue. I have last activity age by using (Today()-Lastactivityage) to calculate last activity age. But I want to segregate it as last task age and last Event age. I have two custom field on opportunity last task age and last event age. I want age of last task when it was done or upcoming. same with event

How can I get these to age in opportunity.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use [declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) to implement `LastTaskDate__c` and `LastEventDatetime__c` fields. Here's how you would set up a `Lookup Rollup Summary` for the `Task` field:

- Parent Object: `MyObject__c`
- Relationship Field: `WhatId`
- Child Object: `Task`
- Field to Aggregate: `ActivityDate`
- Field to Order By: `ActivityDate`
- Aggregate Operation: `Last`
- Aggregate Result Field: `LastTaskDate__c`

Note that you *must* set the same `Field to Order By` as `Field to Aggregate` if you want to use the `Aggregate Operation` options of `First` or `Last`. Setting up a summary for `Event` is almost exactly the same:

- Parent Object: `MyObject__c`
- Relationship Field: `WhatId`
- Child Object: `Event`
- Field to Aggregate: `ActivityDateTime`
- Field to Order By: `ActivityDateTime`
- Aggregate Operation: `Last`
- Aggregate Result Field: `LastEventDatetime__c`